# Add photo from library to contact in wp8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, contacts

In my windows phone application i'm trying to create a new contact and add an image that taken from the camera, but it didn't seems to work.
No matter what i do the photo is blank.
The only way it works for me is by using an image that i added in the assets folder (and not from camera), even trying to add the image to the local assets folder and then to upload it - don't work...

(there is no error, but the contact that was added don't have a photo).

```
await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(stream.AsStream().AsInputStream());
```

Here is my code:
when i get the selected image from store i save it to a bitmapImage and use its pixel buffer.

```
public async void AddContact(string displayName, string mobile, string email, byte[] data)
        {
            var store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();
            var contact = new StoredContact(store)
            {
                DisplayName = displayName
            };

            var props = await contact.GetPropertiesAsync();
            props.Add(KnownContactProperties.Email, email);
            props.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, mobile);

            using (var stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(stream.AsInputStream());
            }
            await contact.SaveAsync();
        }
```

Please help!

Comment: I was able to save image from local storage to contact. can you some more code how you are getting the stream to save it and are you are you calling contact.Save() method to update the thumbnail?

Comment: @Muhammad Saifullah i updated my question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing the same to set profile picture in for contact and it was not working. But when I get IRandomAccessStream from storage file it worked here is what I am doing

```
                var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("filename.jpeg"));
               //Or you can get file direclty from localfolder
               // var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("filename.jpeg");
                using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                {
                    await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(fileStream);
                }
                await contact.SaveAsync();
```

**Edit**
*How to Save picture to local storage using media capture.*

```
 ImageEncodingProperties imgFormat = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        //Save file to local storage
        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(
                "MyPhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imgFormat, file);
```

Once the image is saved in local storage you can get that image from me first example

**Edit 2**
If you are using File open picker you can try this.

```
 public async void ContinueFileOpenPicker(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var filePath  = args.Files[0].Path;
            StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);

            using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                await contact.SetDisplayPictureAsync(fileStream);
            }
       }
```

Comment: Muhammad, thanks for you answer! but what i'm trying to do is not to use a local file but to take a picture from the camera and use it as the contact photo. using the local folder works to me too... have any idea what can be the solution?

Comment: I tried the same thing. Due to some restriction(I cannot remember the link)  it can not set byte Bitmap directly to contact store so app has to store in local or tempstorage to set as contact image.

Comment: One way is to save the image in temp storage and load set profile image from temp storage.
ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("filename.jpeg")

Comment: Can you please attach ypur code for saving to the local store? it didn't works for me, maybe there is something with bitmap image and image store in wondows phone :(

Comment: Ok, What are you doing getting Bitmap of camera directly Or using FileOpenPicker?

Comment: Both. user can use the file open picker to choose a picture from library or take a picture direct from his camera - both options don't work :(